# TypeError: time() missing 1 required positional argument: 'message'

Tags: python, telebot

```
def time(message):
    lesson_name = message.text
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введите время')

def schedule_checker():
    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        sleep(1)

def function_to_run(message):
   return bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "This is a message to send.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
     schedule.every().day.at("10:12").do(time)
```

Вот мой код. Он выдает ошибку TypeError: time() missing 1 required positional argument: 'message'. Почему и что с этим делать?

Comment: Потому что ваша функция `time` требует параметр, а шедулер её запускает без параметра. Откуда вам этот `message` нужно взять при запуске этой функции через шедулер - даже и не представляю.

Comment: @CrazyElf а есть какой-то способ получить chat_id не используя message?

Comment: Ну может запомнить из какой-то другой функции бота, которая вызывается тоже с `message` в глобальную переменную